# Query xml root note

Tags: xml, powershell

I am using this sample as an example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms762271(v=vs.85)

So first I read in the content and the sample into a variable like so:

```
$xmlSample = "C:\Users\David\Documents\XmlSample.dtsx"
[XML]$xml =  Get-Content $xmlSample
```

How can I print the root note without looking into the file? The answer is "catalog" but is it possible to print it? I can only find ChildNodes using `$xml.ChildNodes`

Comment: Try `$xml.DocumentElement.Name` or `$xml.SelectSingleNode('//*').Name` or `$xml.FirstChild.NextSibling.Name`

Comment: @Theo: Thanks, my real file says "DTS:Executable". What should I do with the colon when writing the Xpath

Comment: Without seeing your real (sanitized) file, I think you could try `.LocalName` instead of `.Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) advises:

Use the `[xml]` ([`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument)) type's `.DocumentElement` instance property, which returns an [`System.Xml.XmlElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlElement) instance representing the document (root) element, whose `.LocalName` property returns the element name without any namespace prefix (`.Name` returns the name *with* its namespace prefix, if any):

```
([xml] (Get-Content -Raw $xmlSample)).DocumentElement.LocalName
```